# codeigniter letter at start of every page

Tags: php, debugging, codeigniter-2

I'm working on a website, which I have temporarily hosted [here](http://cmlac.byethost33.com/).

You'll notice the mystery letter 'a' I'm getting at the start of every page. I've gone through all the php files (controllers, views, models) and cannot locate where this letter is coming from. Another curiosity is that all the head content is not residing in the head tags when inspected with Firebug. It appears in the body tags, however it still functions correctly. Are these two issues related?

The only thing I have found from searching the internet is that perhaps some files have been saved as ANSI instead of UTF-8. I've tried 'saving as' all my php files as UTF-8 using my editor, but it is a very slow process. Any help debugging this situation would be appreciated.

EDIT- thanks for your response, @erman-belegu. It doesn't seem to be in any controller. For instance, I've set up a 404 redirect, with its own controller and view. The view looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
         <meta name="description" content="No Page">
      </head>
      <body>
         <h1>No page dude.</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

But when inspected with firebug, it looks like this:

```
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      a
      <meta content="No Page" name="description">
      <h1>No page dude.</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I have encoded everything using UTFCast, and am still experiencing the same issue. Any help welcomed.

Comment: use a bulk conversion tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the head inside the body tag because the mysterious "a" is the first character of your output. It's put inside the body tag by the rendering engine of your browser, or by firebug.

If you find the cause of your "a" - almost certainly some content outside PHP tags - the head will return to normal in firebug.

Searching for the "a" is tricky.. I'm not sure how large your codebase is, but I'd say start by exiting the process right before output is sent. You should see only the "a". Then move the exit step by step untill your "a" disappears, and you'll find it.

Comment: thanks for that. I'm not sure how to find that point in the process with codeigniter. Can you advise me about how to do that or point me at a tutorial?

Comment: Well, I'm not really familiar with codeigniter - but this looks like an ok place to start: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#output  Create the _output function and see if the A is inside the $output variable. (probably not)

Answer (score 0):

Check your controllers at start or maybe any print somewhere. Check all your code on these pages because you print these "a ".

Also use UTF-8 without BOM. But, I think that you print it accidentally and dont think that this happens for any other reasons.